# Outputing shape_Area value from polygon feature to output table in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

In ModelBuilder, I'm using the "Iterate Datasets" tool to iterate though a dataset of polygon features. Each are simple, single, polygons so just the one row in the attribute table. The polygons were generated with a shape_Length and shape_Area column in their attribute table.

I would like to output the area of each polygon feature to a summary table (cvs or similar) containing values for all iterations.

My current model is stuck right at the start with the Iterate Datasets tool which uses a Feature Dataset of polygon features as input. Previously I've just manually copied the shape_Area value from the features into an excel sheet which works but is slow.

[image: model]

Comment: What does your model so far look like?  What does a simple example of your input(s) and desired output(s) look like?  At the moment you are only telling us what you would like to do, when for focussed Q&A we are also wanting to know precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you tried?

Comment: I updated the original post to answer your questions. I think I'm stuck at taking the shape_Area value from each iteration and outputting it to a table.

Comment: Can you include a picture of the model in which you are testing this, please?  There is a picture button that you can use to do that.

Comment: I uploaded the model but, like I said, I'm at the very start so there isn't really much there to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having one polygon per feature class what I would probably do is to Append them into a single feature class and then run Summary Statistics on that i.e. no need for an iterator.

Comment: Seems like the answer which is also simply. I do not think having more than one feature each feature class would be an issue. If OID is used as case field  and any statistics on Shape_area it will be fine.

Comment: That is almost perfect PolyGeo -thanks. It works but the only problem is that the result doesn't have any identifier in the attribute table to identify what row was from what input class. Ideally I'd like to grab the name of the feature class and append it along with the data to the attribute table. Maybe that is a different question though and should be done at an earlier step.

Comment: Nevermind. I quickly found a python script to add the filename to the features which I can run before doing the Append. For reference it is here: [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/how-do-you-add-file-name-to-an-attribute-field)