# Populating field with the name of the input file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I'm using modelbuilder to import a dbf (selected by the user) to a geodatabase and turn it into a feature class for further processing.

I would like to be able to populate a field in the imported table with the original file name of the source data.

This is section of my model where it imports the dbf (named Input Rows by the model) and adds the field but I can't find a way of capturing the input file name to use in Field Calculator

[image]

Edit: I've looked at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/adding-file-name-to-attribute-field-using-calculate-field), but it seems to be talking about adding a field based on the feature class/shape file name. My table will have a generic name, I want to be able to use the name of the file that is being selected to populate it.

The geodatabase is a template that will be re-used by lots of users in different locations with differently named dbfs.

Comment: See this GISSE answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/adding-file-name-to-attribute-field-using-calculate-field

Comment: I've looked at that, it seems to be talking about adding a field based on the feature class or table name. I want it to pick up the name of the file that is being selected to populate a table that has a generic name. It's essentially a template that will be re-used by lots of users in different locations.